# Access Navigation form stop requerying forms

Tags: ms-access

in my MS Access 2013 application, I am using a Navigation Form as a top layer to connect all my subforms.

**How do I stop Access from requerying the subforms whenever I change tabs (forms)** ?!
(Basically I just want to use the navigation tabs as a way switch the other forms that remain open but hidden)

This seems like a basic feature that i cant't seem to figure out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Tabs, NavigationForms has a menu and a subform control where your "target forms" will be "loaded". So every time when you click a navigation button, your target form will be "loaded/opened" into the subform control.

It means you are not re-querying your forms but unloading and loading.

for your purpose you might well use the normal Tabs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a dozen of subforms and I like looks and useability of the navigation form. Is there no way to prevent it from "loading" the subforms? can i change the "on click" event of the navigation controls?

Comment: yes you can prevent loading.. then you wouldn't see the subform :) so whats the point?.. Think the other way.. why are you trying to prevent requery/loading? adjust your query to yield same results no matter how many requery happens

Comment: well, loading the form once and not reloading it after it is opened again would be great. 
in my application the user might want to switch between forms and want to continue on working on the data that he had last opened on the previous form (and not pull it out again through a new search etc...) 

so a solution would be to save the "view" ( the opened queries of the user) in a table before he leaves the form and then reload it when the user returns...
super extravagant for a simple function...